# CodeIgniter Database connection error,Unable to connect to Database Server

Tags: codeigniter

In CodeIgniter, I have Database Error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: mysqli::real_connect():
>
> Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 161

Unable to connect your database server using provided setting.

```
FileName:core/CodeIgniter Line:500
```

I can't understand why this error occured in CodeIgniter

Comment: What version of codeigniter you are using? And please add your database configuration

Answer (score 0):

navigate to **application/config/database.php** and update your database connection settings

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'DATABASE USERNAME';
$db['default']['password'] = 'DATABASE PASSWORD';
$db['default']['database'] = 'DATABASE NAME HERE';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
```

Also make sure that the database is running.

**Note:** CodeIgniter 3 does not work with `mysql`. The database type. ie: `mysqli`, `postgre`, `odbc`, etc. Must be specified in lower case, as pointed out by @wolfgang1983 in comment below.

Comment: Note: CodeIgniter 3 not work with mysql `The database type. ie: mysqli, postgre, odbc, etc. Must be specified in lower case.`

Comment: @wolfgang1983 Thankyou